# Build 3D object of face using iPhone X Truedepth

Tags: ios, truedepth-camera

Is there any good examples or guide on how to create 3D face objects to export/save using iPhone X TrueDepth Camera API ?

This app seems to be able to do it:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bellus3d-faceapp/id1352268131